# Most suitable way for audio streaming using AudioQue?

Tags: iphone, audio, streaming

I am writing an application, which sends audio data to server in real-time.
I have done this task but, some time it make error. I believe, this is due to the bad architecture of my program.
The program content is as follows:

--For audio recording I wrote AudioRecorder class, which has implemented AudioCallBack method which is called by the AudioQueue. Inside this method I capture the audio data into buffer and send to server, using NSOutputStream.

--The streams, NSOutputStream and NSInputStream s are instantiates in the init method of AudioREcorder.

--The stream handle event method (delegated by stream) also implemented the in the same AudioRecorder class.

While developing this application I got following problems

1) I wanted to write Streaming in another class and send the buffer using some method. But it wasnt work. So I implemented it in the same class.

2) When I want to send the "end" message (After clicking end button), I tried to send it inside Button end method using the instance of NSOutputStream. But, it wast success. So, I fixed it putting some parameters inside AudioCallBack.

q1) Why I cannot make streaming part in another class ?
q2) What is the better way to organize this type of application in order to iPhone application development.

/thx

Comment: It would be best beneficial to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have so far to avoid the community doing any heavy lifting.